# How can I stop TastyPie doing UPDATE queries for no reason?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm seeing some usual goings on in my application. For no reason my server slows down when I have little or no traffic. After lots of trial and error I found my problems disappeared when I removed the `ToOneField` on my [TastyPie](http://tastypieapi.org/) resource!

What I found was for some unknown reason TastyPie is doing **DB UPDATES** on these ToOneFields for no good reason! What the... moment!

[image]

I found a possible bug filed [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/397) which claims to have fixed the update issue. I have installed the latest version from `pip` but still see this problem.

Can anyone help?

```
class IncentiveResource(ModelResource):
    product_introducer = fields.ToOneField(ProductResource, 'referrer_product', full=True)
    product_friend = fields.ToOneField(ProductResource, 'referee_product', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Incentive.objects.all().order_by('-date_created')
        resource_name = 'incentive'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authentication = MultiAuthentication(ClientAuthentication(), ApiKeyAuthentication())
        authorization = Authorization()
        filtering = {
            "active": ALL,
        }
        always_return_data = True
        cache = SimpleCache(cache_name='resources', timeout=10)
```

So little traffic here but becomes unusable.
[image]
[image]

Comment: The profiling output shown above...what tool made that?

Comment: @8one6 it's New Relic

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will help you, but I've seen a slight performance increase in an app I worked on while using `select_related` in the queryset and `full=True` in the resource field.

Try `queryset = Incentive.objects.select_related('product_introducer', 'product_friend').all().order_by('-date_created')`

Comment: Hi Farhan thanks for the reply. Yes I also read this and I think it would help, however, the fact that Tastypie is doing the DB UPDATES for no good reason is my main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Can you reproduce the sql UPDATEs in a testing environment?

If yes, here is how I would debug it:

Modify the source where the sql command gets executed: insert an `assert` statement that no update gets done.

If the `assert` fails, you have the stacktrace of the strange UPDATE.

If this stacktrace does not help you, post it here.